# How can I replace values in a deeply nested but arbitrary data structure?

Tags: perl

I have a data structure that is arbitrary. The form is usually similar in that it consists of arrays and hashes about four levels deep, with about two to six values I'd like to change. A typical example:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          [
            {
              '0' => 'some string'
            }
          ],
          undef,
          [
            undef,
            {
              '1033' => 'another string '
            }
          ]
        ];
```

While I know the syntax well enough to access these two values and change them in this particular example (or any other), from one use to the next this will change in ways that hard-coded expressions will fail.

This feels like it should be a simple sub that runs recursively, but once it finds that the element of the data structure is an array or hash, I don't know how to pass the element into the next recursive call by reference such that it can be modified in a non-temporary way. The following code fails recursively (though if it doesn't recurse, it can change a shallow value in the top-level array and this change sticks):

```
sub deep_nested_replace {
    my ($d, $string) = @_;

    if (ref($d) eq 'ARRAY') {
        for (my $i=0; $i<scalar @$d; $i++) {
            deep_nested_replace($d->[$i], $string);
        }
    }
    elsif (ref($d) eq 'HASH') {
        foreach my $k (keys %$d) {
            deep_nested_replace($d->{$k}, $string);
        }
    }
    elsif (defined $d) {
        $d = $string;
    }
}
```

How do I make this work? If this is the wrong approach, what's a correct one?

Comment: with the assignment to `$d` in the first line of the function you are making a copy of the value. if you directly assign to the respective element in `@_`, it should affect the caller data.

Comment: Thanks @Sam. If you'll write up a quick answer, would be happy to select it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@_` array with function parameters contains aliases to the scalars (or otherwise explicit references) passed to the function. Modifications to it *will* affect the caller data. The same with `$_` in `grep` or `map`. This is something that coming from other programming languages you sometimes need to be careful of.

However, by making an assignment from one scalar variable to another, as in the idiomatic `my ($d, $string) = @_`, the scalar value is copied from one variable to another.

If you want to affect a scalar value passed to a function in the caller, you can work directly with the `@_` array and its elements.

```
sub deep_nested_replace {
    my ($d, $string) = @_;

    if (ref($d) eq 'ARRAY') {
        deep_nested_replace($_, $string) for @$d;
    }
    elsif (ref($d) eq 'HASH') {
        deep_nested_replace($_, $string) for values %$d;
    }
    elsif (defined $d) {
        $_[0] = $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added code with the necessary changes (and some simplifications) to the answer. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: i sure don't :)